# jQuery change event is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added change event on the input field so that whenever user enters the text into it, so other task should happen, it works but when i click outside the input field.I don't know whether it is default behavior or i am doing some thing wrong. I tried using `keyup` and `keydown` events and it works as expect.
Please suggest.

Here is my code:

```
 $("#mobile-number").on('change',function(){
   // some other code               
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

The `change` event fires when an elements value changes.

For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element **loses focus**.

In other words, on an input, the `change` event fires when the element loses focus, not when you type, and that is the default behaviour.

That's why there are key events as well, and on modern browsers you can catch most changes to an input with the `input` event

```
$("#mobile-number").on('input',function(){ ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the desired behavior.

[Change Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

> The change event is fired for , , and 
>   elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the
>   user. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily
>   fired for each change to an element's value.
>
> Depending on the kind of form element being changed and the way the
>   user interacts with the element, the change event fires at a different
>   moment:
>
> - When the element is activated (by clicking or using the keyboard) for  and ;
> - When the user commits the change explicitly (e.g. by selecting a value from a 's dropdown with a mouse click, by selecting a
>     date from a date picker for , by selecting a file
>     in the file picker for , etc.);
> - When the element loses focus after its value was changed, but not commited (e.g. after editing the value of  or ).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `input` event:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#mobile-number").on('input', function() {
    $("#copy").val(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='mobile-number' />
<input type='text' id='copy' readonly/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:( If i really understand your problem )

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#mobile-number', function() {
   // some other code               
 });
```

for type event:

```
jQuery(document).on('keyup', '#mobile-number', function() {
   // some other code               
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your selector to the .on function:

```
$(document).on('change', '#mobile-number', function() {
    // some other code               
});
```